# Nodejs request with fs.createWriteStream writes zero bytes when within socket function io.on

Tags: node.js, socket.io, request, fs

I'm attempting to use request to retrieve an image file from a remote resource and write the stream to a directory on my server. This works using the code below, but my file has no data:

```
io.on(myVar, function(socket){
var requestSettings = {
  url: 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png',
  method: 'GET',
  encoding: null
};
var imgpath="./public/img/file.png";

var response_stream = request(requestSettings)
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(imgpath))
  .on('close', function() {
      console.log('This will be the last line printed');
  })
  .on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('err', err);
  });
console.log("Move to the next line in the code");
});
```

The problem I'm running into is when `fs.createWriteStream` is within `io.on(myVar, function(socket){//write the file});` zero bytes are written to the file.

I know I'm missing something fundamental, I just don't know what it is.

Is this a question of asychronous functions and timing?

Comment: Are you 100% sure there are no error messages in the console?  What happens if you put an error handler on your stream (`.on("error", ...)`?  Anything show if you surround the code with a try/catch that logs in the catch?

Comment: Plus, `.on('close')` should be passed a function as the second argument.

Comment: I updated like so.... There are no errors in the console log. var response_stream = request(requestSettings).on('close').pipe(fs.createWriteStream(imgpath)).on('error', function (err) { console.log("There was an error")});

Comment: Why are you using `.on('close')`?  That makes no sense as it does nothing because it isn't passed an event handler.  Remove that.

Comment: You said to use it.. I'm not sure where to put it??

Comment: I said that if you use `.on('close', fn)`, you HAVE to pass it a function as the second argument. Otherwise it does nothing and may even cause an error. If you have no code you're trying to execute on the close event, then just remove it.  `.on('close')` all by itself does nothing.

Comment: Same view as @jfriend00, you should add callback function there, or simnple remove `.on('close')` to get it works as normal.

Comment: createWriteStream(imgpath) writes zero bytes if there is no .on('close), or .on('end'). This is also true if I add a second function with say a console.log('Closed/Ended')...

Comment: Note, that when I remove .on('close') it  *does* progress to the next line. It just writes zero bytes now.

Comment: Try/catch does return an error... Thank you for that. 
"There was an error: *TypeError: listener must be a function*"

Comment: Note that I have updated my question and code based on this comment thread and the answer below. I discovered that this issue is only happening for me within io.on using socket.io. Outside of the io.on function the answer below does work.

Comment: I've checked also, and it works without socketio. so if it works being outside of io context, it means You're missing `request` or `fs` variables or they are being replaced with something else. try to add in same file with io.on following lines: `const request = require('request'); const fs = require('fs');` and check again. btw You can put: `process.stdout` as pipe argument to see if it even being piped.

Comment: @num8er I put `const request = require('request'); const fs = require('fs');` directly below io.on and directly above the sample non-working code. It is still writing zero bytes.

Comment: @num8er I added `process.stdout` as a pipe argument like this `    .process.stdout(function(){
      console.log("stdout happened");
    })`. There was no console output. Also file has bytes now, but node does not proceed to the next line in the code. I still feel that I am missing something fundamental. I thought perhaps I need async-await?

Comment: @Dshiz a bit stupid question: can You put `console.log('testing pipe';` inside of `io.on` scope?) Just to test if it's even being called.

Comment: Io.on scope is being called.. Otherwise it wouldn't create the 0byte file.

Comment: This appears to be a bug: https://github.com/request/request/issues/887

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and got the following error and got the `listener` TypeError

```
events.js:238
throw new TypeError('"listener" argument must be a function');
^

TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function
```

Looking up the docs, We can see that `close` event takes a functions as an argument

**Event: 'close'**

> Indicates that the underlying connection was closed. Just like 'end', this event occurs only once per response.

**Source** [Node.js doc](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_close_2)

So, making those changes to your code

```
'use strict';

let request = require('request');
let fs = require('fs');

var requestSettings = {
    url: 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png',
    method: 'GET',
    encoding: null
};
var imgpath = "./file.png";
var response_stream = request(requestSettings)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(imgpath))
    .on('close', function() {
        console.log('This will be the last line printed');
    })
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('err', err);
    });
console.log("Move to the next line in the code");
```

This prints

> Move to the next line in the code
>   This will be the last line printed

Comment: This is writing a zero byte file.

Comment: I've noticed that this code will work fine outside of socket.io ->   socket.on('url', function(somevar) {//stuff happens-> your code}... What is going on!

Comment: @Dshiz With the update question, I am not sure how the socket.io would affect the file writing. Can you check whether you're triggering write action multiple times, since it is inside socket listener

Comment: I'm also writing to a file-based database within the same socket.io listener. Do you think that might be causing a problem when I try to write the file in my sample code?